# Is it possible to enable sbh52 headset microfone?

Tags: bluetooth, headset

Is it possible with the Sony add-on SDK to enable the sbh52 bluetooth microphone? I want to enable the microphone and sent it to the phone to enable Google Now (voice commands/search). The microphone is only enabled when on a call. But you should be able to trick the headset to enable it when you want?

Comment: Please add what programming language are you working with, and some more contextual info of your problems so it is easier for other users to provide an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Tasker to enable the bluetooth mic.
The AutoVoice plugin got an action called 'AutoVoice Ctrl BT' that starts the microphone on the Sony sbh52.

Now Google Now works :-)